# Ducking. When I accept call in my VoIP-softphone, the Volume level in my softphone drops down to 10% , if I use default audio device (Windows 8)

Tags: c++, windows, voip

I am working VoIP softphone which used webrtc. And I have meet follow issue:

When I accept call in my softphone, the Volume level in my softphone drops down to 10%.
It is reproduced, when few audio devices are connected to PC and the default audio device (not headset) is used in my softphone.

I tried to disable "ducking" using WASAPI function "SetDuckingPreference", but it not help.

Could you please help me?
Please let me know why the volume is dropped down. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Default device volume level (on use) is `None`(so mean not bussy). How to configure level without any declaration(your ear can be damaged.). Need set a static level(isn't good option) or set initial value if Voip app on first running.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj870738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx